# Mongodb projection not working for java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a document in this format :

```
{
 "env" : "local",
 ....,
 "daily" : [
    {
     "executionParam1" : "Apple",
     "executionParam2" : "sour",
     "executionParam3" : "today",
     ...
    },
    {
     "executionParam1" : "Oranges",
     "executionParam2" : "sour",
     "executionParam3" : "tomorrow",
     ....
    }...
 ]
```

I query it using MongoDB java driver. The query is in this form:

```
this.mongoDailyReportCollection = this.mongoDb.getCollection("environments");
Bson projection = fields(excludeId(),
                                 include("env", "daily"),
                                 Projections.elemMatch("daily",
                                                       and(eq("executionParam1", coll.getexecutionParam1()),
                                                           eq("executionParam2", coll.getexecutionParam2()),
                                                           eq("executionParam3", coll.getexecutionParam3()))));
long count = this.mongoDailyReportCollection.count(projection);
```

I keep getting count as 0 even when the executionParam1 is Apple, executionParam2 is sour and executionParam3 is today. If I want to update the document that matches this one then what would be the procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending projection document to `count` method which accepts query document.

```
Bson filter = Filters.elemMatch("daily", and(eq("executionParam1", coll.getexecutionParam1()), eq("executionParam2", coll.getexecutionParam2()), eq("executionParam3", coll.getexecutionParam3())));

long count = this.mongoDailyReportCollection.count(filter);
```

You will use the positional operator with set modifier to update the field matching from query filter.

The below query will update `executionParam1` to `Banana`.

Something like

```
this.mongoDailyReportCollection.updateOne(filter, Updates.set("daily.$.executionParam1", "Banana"));
```